# What is an example of a boilerplate A-Frame 1.0.4+ component project with working tests?

Tags: testing, aframe

I'm looking to have basic testing of an A-Frame component to verify the modifications it makes to the scene and DOM.

I have attempted to use the `angle` repo https://github.com/ngokevin/angle to init a new component which includes pre-configured tests with karma, as recommended by this post: [Writing test specs for A-Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41916358/writing-test-specs-for-a-frame)

However the default test in `angle` does not run, resulting in this error in the console:
`You need to include some adapter that implements __karma__.start method!`

Is there any example of a working A-Frame component test that I can build from?

Comment: Ok I found [state component](https://github.com/supermedium/superframe/tree/master/components/state/) tests run with a relevant `Uncaught TypeError: navigator.xr.requestDevice is not a function` probably related to webxr changes

Comment: This [stats in vr component](https://github.com/chenzlabs/stats-in-vr) runs tests successfully, but it's A-Frame 0.4.0

Comment: The [A-Frame repo itself](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe) includes working tests if run with `npm run test:chrome` (firefox throws errors related to "vrdisplaypresentchange") but it is way too big. I'll take a look at difference between A-Frame test setup and `angle` repo

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the tests to run successfully using the `angle` repo when I also add envify and browserify-css by running `npm install --save envify browserify-css` to the new project. Now the sample test is running.

Here are the complete steps that resolved this issue:

- I made a new directory for my project and navigate there. I did `npm init` in that directory and entered some info about my project.
- Then I ran `npm install angle` (I tried `sudo npm install -g angle` but it didn't work.)
- Then I ran `node ./node_modules/angle/index.js initcomponent` and entered in some info about my new component.
- Then I had to navigate to the newly created subdirectory. Then I ran `npm install`
- Then I run  `npm install --save envify browserify-css`
- Then I run `npm run test`
- Then I see `SUMMARY: ✔ 2 tests completed`